# Making an alias which maps arguments to the middle of the command

Tags: shell, zsh, alias

I want to alias `killapp X` to `pidof X | xargs kill` or `` kill `pidof X` ``, but I can't think of a way to do this with just an alias on `killapp`. How could I do this so I don't have to do `` killapp X` `` ?

Comment: Are you aware of [`killall`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/killall.1.html)?

Comment: on a mac, the name of the `.app` application package is NOT necessarily the same as the name of the process.

Comment: So I can `killall Mathematica` all I want, but the `MathKernel` processes will never go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with an alias, because it only expands an abbreviation. However, we do have functions:

```
function killapp ()
{
    pidof $1 | xargs kill
}
```

Comment: I should really learn to use those.

Comment: To see what a function definition looks like you can use the command `declare -f killapp` to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an alias:

```
alias al='(read arg; echo The arg is: "$arg".) <<<'
```

```
al something
> The arg is: "something".
```